# Simply connected Lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra

I am reading through "Physics through symmerty" (Jakob Schwichtenberg) and he introduces a theorem which states that there is precisely one simply connected Lie group (the covering group) for each Lie algebra, and all others follow from this one through mappings.

So SU(2) is the simply connected lie group (the simply connected three sphere) and SO(3) is a 2-1 map of this.

However I don't understand how this applies to U(1) and SO(2). My guess would be that U(1) is the unique simply connected lie group (since its a simply connected circle), but it's a 1-1 map to go from U(1) to SO(2) so wouldn't that mean that they're Lie algebra does not have a unique simply connected Lie group? Which one is the covering group?

Comment: A simply connected circle??

Comment: If there's a 1-1 map to go from $U(1)$ to $SO(2)$ then they're the same group.

Comment: U(1) and SO(2) are the same group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathrm{U}(1)$ and $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ are isomorphic as Lie groups, and as manifolds they're diffeomorphic to the circle $S^1$, which is not simply connected.

The unique 1-dimensional simply connected Lie group is the Abelian group $(\mathbb{R},+)$, which is the universal cover of $\mathrm{U}(1)\cong\mathrm{SO}(2)\cong S^1$ via [$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/274841/143136).

Comment: Okay that makes sense, there is a different covering group which can be mapped to U(1) (and thus SO(3)). Is there  a geometric picture of the Abelian group $(R",+)$? Like SU(2) is an $S^3$ and U(1) is a unit circle.

Comment: @GihaadHammam Geometrically $\mathbb{R}$ is just an infinite line (it's the real numbers, after all). The covering map to the circle can be visualized as the projection of an infinite helix (which is just a line, hence $\mathbb{R}$) down to a circle.